# Distinguish between removed or deleted in FIRDocumentChangeType

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My main goal is to mix pagination in firestore with the real-timeniness.
Is there a way to know within a Snapshotlistener if an object was removed, because it didn't match the query anymore, or if the object was deleted? The documentation for FIRDocumentChangeTypeRemoved says "(either deleted or no longer matches the query". Is there any way to know which one of those actually happened?

My approach looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    getFirstBatchOfItems()
}

private func getFirstBatchOfItems() {
 //getting initial 20 items and storing them in an array 'items'


self.startListeningForUpdates()
}

private func startListeningForUpdates() {        
    questionItemsListener = Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("items")
        .whereField("active", isEqualTo: true)
        .order(by: "updated", descending: true)
        .limit(to: 5) //keep track of the last 5 updates
        .addSnapshotListener({ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching querySnapshot: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            
            querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach { (diff) in
                switch diff.type {
                case .added:
                    if let newItem = try docSnapshot?.data(as: Item.self) {
                        //only add new items if these dont exist in the items list yet
                        if !self.items.contains(newItem) {
                            self.items.append(newItem)
                        }
                    }
                case .modified:
                    if let modifiedItem = try docSnapshot?.data(as: Item.self) {
                        let index = self.items.firstIndex(of: modifiedItem) {
                        self.items[index] = modifiedItem
                    }
                case .removed:
                    if let removeItem = try docSnapshot?.data(as: Item.self) {
// 2 Things to check
// 1. Was the item deleted? If yes, then remove the item from the item array 
// 2. If the item doesn't match the query anymore - check if it is just because of the limit which was set - If the limit was surpassed then keep item in array 
                        self.questionItems.remove(object: newItem)
                    }
                }
                self.sortItemsByDate()
                print("Count of items: \(self.questionItems.count)")
            }
            
            self.applySnapshot(items: items, animated: true)
        })
}
```

First I am getting an initial batch of items I want to display (20). Then I am adding a snapshotlistener that should add, update, or remove the items to the initial array. Initially there are going to be 5 duplicates because I am invoking the listener after I have already gotten the first 20 items. Therefore I am checking for .add whether the item already exists and only add it to the array if it does't. For modifications .modified I just update the respective item. And now the tricky part. When an Item is .removed it can be because of 1. deletion or 2. it doesnt fit the query anymore. If the items gets deleted I want to remove it from my array. However, if it gets removed because it doesn't fit the query anymore, and more specifically, because it surpassed the limit of 5, I want to keep it, and not remove it.
Here is a numbers example.

The initial item array is populated with items 1 through 20 [1...20]. Then I call the listener to check for any updats that might occur. This gets the first 5 items, again [1...5]. Through my logic I just skip the items as they already exists. The problem is now if a new item is added. The listener picks it up and adds it to the the array but also tells me to remove one item as the limit of 5 is reached. I can't distinguish between a deletion (item was really deleted from firestore) and a removal (doesn't fit the query anymore). I am using 'FirebaseCore', '~> 6.6.0'

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to distinguish between these two cases in your `.removed` handler:

1. The document fell out of the query results, but still exists in the database.
2. The document was removed from the database, and thus also from the query results.

I don't think there is any metadata passed along in the `QuerySnapshot`/`QueryDocumentSnapshot` to distinguish between these two cases.  The only thing I can think of is to try and load the document, but that'd be a pretty expensive operation.

Comment: Same problem with that documentation. It also says “ (either deleted or no longer matches the query” I still don’t see a way to differentiate between deletion and match.

Comment: In that case: can you edit your question to show your code and what version of what libraries you include?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I had missed it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Being able to distinguish between the document falling out of the query or having been removed because it is deleted is a highly needed feature. Documents have a metadata field "exists" but it is misleading - you would think it means "document exists in firestore" but that is not what it means.

Comment: @Micro: I agree that this would be a useful feature, but it's not how the API currently works - which is what OP asked about. I recommend [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) rather than downvoting the correct answer to the question that was asked here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Indeed you are correct. In repentance, I shall not only un-downvote your comment. I will up-vote it ⬆️ - edit: oh great, it won't let me change my vote "You last voted on this answer 21 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." - if you edit it, I can change my vote.

Comment: done... look at us gaming the system ;-)

Comment: I won't tell if you won't tell 